# can't import StreamingContext in spark2.1.0 through scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Big Data environment so i don't know much,but i have researched and added dependency in my pom file but i can't create spark `StreamingContext`. I am attaching the images of dependency and the error below

- [Showing error not found type StreamingContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQapf.png)
- [List of dependency i have pasted in my pom file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kF7C.png)

Any help would be of great help.
I am using `spark` version 2.1.0 and `scala` version 2.11.8

Comment: You have not imported StreamingContext

Answer (score 0):

Please be more careful about your imports.

From the [Spark API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$) we can see that:

StreamingContext object's absolute package path is

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
```

**But your image shows that you have this import pattern.**

```
import org.apache.spark._
```

**This is the point why your ide can not find the StreamingContext reference.**

The solution is clear, two choices:

1. `import org.apache.spark.streaming._`
2. `import org.apache.spark._` and refer it **streaming.StreamingContext** in program